# Notification "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – participate in meta" for the reputation gain in Meta

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, notifications

I am a meta user already and gained some initial reputation. On that, I got a notification like the one shown below in the image:

"Congrats, you've gained the privilege – participate in meta"

[image]

This is a probable bug since I am already a Meta user and this notification stands irrelevant now.

Comment: Similar notification bug in case of "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – talk in chat" as well though I am a chat user earlier itself.

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to meta.

Comment: @psubsee2003, may be a duplicate. But, unfortunately it was asked even more than a year before the question you pointed and went unanswered. :)

Comment: @RinoTom time asked is completely irrelevant.  It answers your question, does it not?  We don't need 2 or 3 questions open on the same topic

Comment: @psubsee2003, I accept this is duplicate and even marked the and accepted the answer for the other question is answering this as well. Time is relevant in the sense that the second is added as a duplicate without actually serching out whehter there is already question on it existing.