# Why is the participate in meta privilege shown at rep 5 for MSO?

Tags: discussion, privileges, documentation

I was going through privileges given on MSO according to reputation. We all know MSO is not tied with reputation on main site i.e. SO.

And for participating on MSO we require only 1 reputation. But [this page of  participate in meta privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) says we require 5 reputation.

However I believe we show this privilege page shown over all community sites.

But as dynamically we are changing which is meta site for every main site in this question.

> **Where is meta?**
>       There is a link to meta in the footer and header of every page.
>       Our meta naming convention is standard. The meta site for Meta Stack Overflow is at:
>       http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Similarly we can also change for following question.

> **Why do I need 5 rep to post there?**
>      The following applies to all per-site Metas except Stack Overflow. You do not need Stack Overflow rep to post on its Meta, and your rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site.

This can be applicable for all network sites. But for MSO this privilege should be showed at reputation 1. Isn't it?

And I have checked 1 relative question to this question [Notification "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – participate in meta" for the reputation gain in Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134865/notification-congrats-youve-gained-the-privilege-participate-in-meta-for-t). If we set reputation 1 for participate in meta privilege, this bug will be solved for sure.

Comment: That page serves as the master page for all the privileges pages elsewhere on the network. It's the only privileges wiki set that can be edited, and the changes made there get pushed to all sites on the network when the devs update it.

Comment: I was knowing that but we are dynamically saying in `Where is meta?` about it's meta site. Then why doesn't it will be possible to change the reputation to 1 from 5 as we are all enthusiast programmers. I believe it can be possible to solve this problem.

Comment: *shrugs* Because no one cares?

Comment: Yeah. Surely that's why this is still present. :P This doesn't matter to anyone. But it is bit confusing to new joiners on MSO. We all know people don't require rep for participating on MSO. But let's not confuse to new joiners.

Comment: Well, eventually when MSE spawns, then the privilege will be accurate again. So why not leave it and let time correct the wiki? :)

Comment: Yes why not. Let's hope for birth of MSE. And it will be solving many related problems of separate existence of MSO.

Comment: `I was knowing that but we are dynamically saying in Where is meta? about it's meta site. Then why doesn't it will be possible to change the reputation to 1 from 5 as we are all enthusiast programmers.` There's a difference between concatenating strings with variables `"The meta site for " + SiteName + " is at: http://meta." + SiteDomain + ".com"` and pulling in an if statement with a hardcoded site name or adding another setting for *just one site*.

Comment: @UristMcBobby Actually, the text for that privilege wiki page is: "Our meta naming convention is standard. The meta site for $SiteName is at: $MetaUrl." `$SiteName` and `$MetaUrl` are replaced before the privilege page is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give it a try!

Short answer:

Because it's a design bug. :-) which will be fixed sooner or later, see [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015)

Long answer:

I only recently joined the SO network and I'm also confused by the fact that two pages on SO

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta

state that I needed 5 reputations to participate in the MSO.

However, I only have 1 reputation at SO and still I can participate in MSO.

This must be because Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) and Stack Overflow (MSO) do not share reputations but they seem to the pages listed above.

All other communities on the Stackexchange network share their reputations with the corresponding meta site. And consequently sharing of the help pages poses no problem.

Regarding your statement "we show this privilege page shown over all community sites.": Not completely. At least the top of the page that states when the privilege will be awarded is obviously created dynamically. For example the privilege page on "Ask Patents" shows that only **1 reputation** is needed to get the privilege, but the text says "Why do I need **5 rep** to post there?", see screenshot:
[image]