# Participate in Meta privilege on Meta S.E

Tags: bug, meta

The privileges page for Meta.Stackexchange.com (MSE) lists "Participate In Meta" as a privilege. I think that it should be removed as a privilege on MSE (unless we get a meta.meta.stackexchange.com per site child meta, which would be awesome ;-).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138099/why-is-the-participate-in-meta-privilege-shown-at-rep-5-for-mso?rq=1 looks like dupe - but isn't - as it is from the time before MSO/MSE split.

Comment: MSE is how commonly one refers to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Since Meta SE is a new site, I think it is advisable not to use the same acronym.

Comment: @GitGud There are 11 SE sites that start with the letter M, so MSE, without context, cannot be used to refer to Mathematics.  That's simply the M-site you're most used to referring to.

Comment: @Servy You're probably right. This is still troublesome.

Comment: Alas, there are only so many letters in the English alphabet.

Comment: @GitGud no, it's clear from context.

Comment: @djechlin No, it isn't. I saw the title on this question thinking it would be something related to Mathematics S.E. and it wasn't. Nothing in the title offered enough context.

Comment: @GitGud you were on meta.stackexchange.com, that's context. And anyway this is how acronyms work in general, and while on meta.stackexchange.com, MSE is more likely to refer to meta.stackexchange.com. PHP does not mean the same thing to me as it does to my physician, and while hanging out with a bunch of physicians I'll have to be aware of those things.

Comment: @djechlin I disagree that the analogy applies, because as far as I understand, Meta S.E. is supposed to deal also with Mathematics S.E..

Comment: @GitGud but...  Meta S.E. *is* Meta S.E. Anyway, I suggest getting used to it, acronyms tend to be more populist than democratic.

Comment: You could assume that the majority of the people who've used this site over the years are well used to MSE, in context, not referring to math.se and, as someone who's newer, you may need to learn the norms of somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

The privilege exists here because it *has to exist here*. Now that Meta SE has split off, it has become the source site for all the privilege wikis across the network, so the privilege and its wiki has to be available here in order to be that source.

So the real issue is exactly the same as the [duplicate question you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138099/why-is-the-participate-in-meta-privilege-shown-at-rep-5-for-mso) (the split of Meta SO and Meta SE makes abslutely no difference here) - the privilege should be changed to 1 reputation because anyone with an account can come post here. They already do the same thing with the "access review queues" privilege. That privilege is normally granted at 500 reputation but since the review queues mentioned in the privilege don't actually exist on meta sites, it was bumped up to 2,000 reputation here, because that's when you *actually* gain access to your first review queue here. They can't just remove the privilege, because they need it to be present.

Comment: That's a perfect technical explanation, so maybe I should retag this to feature-request to make the privilege wiki more flexible.